# In R data.table, reshape on multiple columns fails when args are passed as named lists

Tags: r, data.table

In R data.table, it is possible to reshape on multiple columns by passing a list of column names (value.var=) along with a list of aggregation functions (fun.aggregate=). This works well when those lists are explicitly passed to the function arguments. It appears to result in an error condition if the lists are passed as variables.

For example, lets create a data table `dt` as follows:

```
dt = data.table(x=sample(5,20,TRUE), y=sample(2,20,TRUE), 
                z=sample(letters[1:2], 20,TRUE), d1 = runif(20), d2=1L)
```

The reshape operation on two columns, d1 and d1, works with arguments passed as follows:

```
dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun=list(sum, mean), value.var=list("d1", "d2"))
```

However, the same operations fails when arguments are passed as named variables.

```
funs = list(sum, mean)
vars = list("d1", "d2")
dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun=funs, value.var=vars)
```

The error message is:

```
Error in aggregate_funs(fun.call, lvals, sep, ...) : 
  When 'fun.aggregate' and 'value.var' are both lists, 'value.var' must be either of length =1 or =length(fun.aggregate)
```

Is this a bug, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Update: Tried in R version 3.5.0 and data.table version 1.11.4 on Windows. In the actual scenario, my table has 171 columns and over 300,000 rows. The pivot operation involves 31 columns. I have unexpectedly encountered an error in trying to pass function arguments as variables instead of long "in situ" lists. I am looking for an explanation why this error condition occurs. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is very odd that this error is occurring. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) used in the [`aggregate_funs`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/3f835d434cee1a2fdef8a25122c1428121c17be6/R/fcast.R#L59) function in `data.table` package. I would think about submitting an issue to the [`data.table` Github repo](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), as this shouldn't be considered wanted behaviour.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to package authors to be suggesting an issue submission when you have not reproduced the error with a current version of R and the package.

Comment: @42- I run R 3.5.0 and data.table 1.11.4. Those are I think the latest versions. The example the OP gives reproduces exactly.

Comment: Then your issue submission will need to be more complete in your description of your setup to include OS and other packages that might be interfering, because I'm not getting any error. It was in the help page and it didn't throw an error during compilation by either the package author or CRAN.

Comment: No, the code that OP says gives an error is not in the examples in the docs.
In the examples, there is the line where the function is called with passing `...fun=list(sum, mean), value.var=list("d1", "d2")` and that works, as the OP said already. When you instead pass variables which are lists, as `..., fun=funs, value.var=vars)`, the error appears. That is the problem that the OP is talking about. Do you not get an error even when running the last 3 lines of code in the question?

Comment: Yes I get an error but I also got an error with `dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun=funs, value.var=list("d1","d2") )` and I found that changing a list to an atomic vector solved the error. And the help page illustrated using an atomic vector so I'm puzzled that you are not accepting this answer and apparently even downvoting a workign example.  ????

Comment: Actually, it's not my question :) Does `dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun=funs, value.var=c("d1","d2"))` work for you? I get an error again that a function `funs` could not be found. That indicates that there is a bug in parsing the fun argument if it's passed as a variable. Passing everything with `list(...), list(...)` (or `c(...)`) like in the example isn't answering the OP's problem, but rather providing a workaround, which the OP explicitly said s/he wants to avoid, as s/he (I would presume) wants to avoid hard coding the fun and value.var arguments.

Comment: @42- In my opinion, it's fine if in the form of "looks like maybe a bug. you might want to check out their guidance: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support " Anyway, it was long ago filed and gets refiled every so often like https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2064 As far as "current version of R", it should be sufficient to test on any version that the package purports to support (... I don't really have strong opinions on this; just saying.)

Comment: @Blaza Thank you for your recommendation. I have filed a bug as you have suggested after reproducing in the latest version of R and data.table. Thank you so much for your support!

Comment: @Frank: The "issue" might be different. I'm getting an error only when I use a length-2 list as an argument to `value.var`, but _not_ when I use a length-2 character vector. I don't understand the negative votes for a response that offers successful code. I don't have a Windows machine. Why should that be a reason for downvotes???.

Comment: @42- Your answer looks fine to me. Yeah, I misread the problem -- the issue I linked does not seem to be quite the same. I'm so used to seeing the problem in my link that I did not realize this was not another instance of it. (That issue is: when programmatically passing `fun=`, I've invariably run into trouble.) Btw, downvotes may be because with two lists sum applies to d1 and mean to d2 while character vector takes the combo. (Not sure; haven't tested myself.)

Answer (score -1):

It's expecting a character vector rather than a list:

```
 dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun=list(sum, mean), value.var=c("d1","d2"))
   x y  d1_sum_a  d1_sum_b d2_sum_a d2_sum_b d1_mean_a d1_mean_b d2_mean_a d2_mean_b
1: 1 1 0.3437415 1.7922195        1        3 0.3437415 0.5974065         1         1
2: 2 1 0.0000000 0.5831969        0        1       NaN 0.5831969       NaN         1
3: 2 2 0.6644480 0.5086218        1        2 0.6644480 0.2543109         1         1
4: 3 1 2.0642855 0.9072466        3        3 0.6880952 0.3024155         1         1
5: 3 2 0.0000000 0.7751363        0        1       NaN 0.7751363       NaN         1
6: 4 2 0.5024032 0.8132855        1        1 0.5024032 0.8132855         1         1
7: 5 2 0.1153944 0.8494716        1        2 0.1153944 0.4247358         1         1
```

Run on a Mac (El Capitan) running R 3.5.0 and data.table 1.14.1

Comment: Changing my code to `vars=c("d1", "d2")` to align with your approach above also produces an error condition, albeit a different one. Again, my main goal is to supply the arguments as variables in place of "in situ" lists. Thanks!

Comment: I guess we need to compare versions of `data.table` and maybe other packages that are loaded, since I get no error. I'm on package 1.11.4 and hte help page for dcast.data.table says using multiple `value.var` values is "NEW".

Comment: My R version is 3.3.3 on Windows with data.table 1.10.4. The example I picked is from the R documentation for the version. Your version appears to be the latest on CRAN. I will try upgrading to your version and post the results. Appreciate your sharing that you have no error with 1.11.4. Thanks!

Comment: You were two major versions behind in R. I sometimes run one major version behind for a month after a major release, but I never run two versions behind.

Comment: Leaving my answer up, despite the negative votes. I think it's useful to know that it is an OS specific problem. I don't the link to ../issues/2064 is on-point for this issue. The code succeeds with certain forms of arguments on a Mac and probably Linux (since no error was thrown when the package was submitted to CRAN.)